# What user permissions are used by SSIS during execution of packages?

Tags: permissions, ssis

SSIS pacckages contains a script, that checks, whether directory exists. Directory.Exists() method returns false, but I have an access for the folder as Administrator. How could I determine, what user permissions are used during SSIS packages execution.

Comment: I've checked, what account executes my packages, and I have the following problem. This account has all permissions to the folder, but I receive "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." error, when I try to move file to the folder. When I test SSIS packages from Visual Studio it fails until I'll go to the folder using Windows Explorer and entering credentials the first time, then everything works in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are running it. From BIDS, it's the user running it, from SQL Agent it's generally the SQL Agent account. From a stored procedure it's generally the SQL Server account.

To find out for sure, monitor the DTEXEC process using ProcMon

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments from @ElectricLlama, you can also execute a SSIS package in the context of a different set of credentials via a proxy account.